# C# Desktop Forms Framework to use Windows.System

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, .net-framework-version

I'm not using UWP, this is a standard Desktop App using .NET Framework. I'm looking to use the following, but this is only for UWP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync?view=winrt-22621

```
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.Overload("LaunchUriWithDataAsync")]
public static IAsyncOperation<bool> LaunchUriAsync(System.Uri uri, LauncherOptions options, ValueSet inputData);
```

When someone has their Microphone disabled or access turned off, I want to route them to the correct location to to be changed.  Zoom does this today.
[image]

The only place I found where I can do this is within UWP with Namespace:
Windows.System.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That just opens a URL. Specifically, it opens one of [the `ms-settings:` locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#ms-settings-uri-scheme-reference). In Framework, you do it with [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-8.0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ms-settings:privacy-microphone")
```

I'm not sure that's exactly the intended page, but it should be close enough for you to get what you need.

Comment: L.I.B.   I looked at it as a Uri and was attempting through HttpClient, which can't be done, because it was requiring http://..     ha..  I tried running that at the Start->Run command and that only brought up my browser.   Who would of thunk it.   Thanks.